# call ASP page method from html page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a static HTMl page index.html with text boxes for getting data.

I want to post this data to ASP page Default.aspx using jquery/AJAX .

I tried this

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            success: function (data2) {
                alert("success::");

            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("ERROR:::" + response.d);
            }
        });
```

But this is showing undefined error.

Help me with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `[WebMethod]` attribute over you page method.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes , i did that [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentTime()
    {}

Comment: @user1491927 put your function in your question